# How do i launch SMS mobile app from a QR code scanning using angularx-qrcode library?

Tags: angular, sms, qr-code

Original (documentation):

```
<qrcode [qrdata]="'Your data string'" [width]="256" [errorCorrectionLevel]="'M'"></qrcode>
```

What i want:

```
<qrcode [qrdata]="<Open SMS app with the the number to send and text i need to write>" [width]="256" [errorCorrectionLevel]="'M'"></qrcode>
```

Answer (score 0):

I already knew how to achieve it

This is the way:

```
<qrcode [qrdata]="'SMSTO:<phonenumber>:<Text message here>'"[width]="256" [errorCorrectionLevel]="'M'"></qrcode>
```